# {{link-to}} emberJS opening a new webpage from different domain

Tags: ember.js

I am new to emberJS and I am trying to open a new page like 'www.google.com' from one of my page where I have my link specified in my HBS template like below.

```
{{#link-to 'applications.google' tagName="li"}}<a href="">Google</a>{{/link-to}}
```

I tried to insert the {{action}} helper inside the  tag also, and wrote an action method in the controller, yet it didn't work.  Not sure.  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal anchor tag with full URL with protocol.

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'> example </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I currently have an ember URL like - 'localhost:4200/applications' and when I add the link 'www.google.com' in the HREF of anchor tag, it shows the link as 'http://localhost:4200/applications/www.google.com'.   Hence it's not working.

Comment: I did added an action helper in the href like <a target="_blank" href="" {{action "openGoogle"}}> and in the controller i included an action as '    window.open("https://www.google.com");'.   It worked. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update your question with your current code changes

Answer (score 0):

I did added an action helper in the HRef tag like

And in the Ember Controller I included an action as

```
    actions: {
      openGoogle() {
           window.open("google.com");
      }
    }
```

It works!!!

Comment: Why do you need actions here ?. Instead of `{{#link-to 'applications.google' tagName="li"}}<a href="">Google</a>{{/link-to}}` you can just replace `<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>` . this will work.

Comment: I am sure my answer will work correct, you don't need action `openGoogle` here.

Comment: To create an action in the Ember Controller is a bit overkill. @Kumkanillam solution is a lot easier and much less code. My own website (made in Ember) did what @Kumkanillam suggested:  `<a class="linkText" target="_blank" href="https://www.github.com/keanedawg"> GitHub</a>`. No Controller actions necessary.